# Incorrect syntax near ')' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, business-objects

I am getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

while trying to run the SQL query shown below on SAP Business Objects Information design tool. The query executes just fine from SQL Server, but from SAP Information design tool, I get this incorrect syntax error while trying to see the table values.

SQL Error:

[image: SQL Error]

Valid SQL

[image: Valid SQL]

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('Callaway.CRM.DAL.Objects.VisitActivityDetail' as ns)
SELECT 
    r.value('(ns:*)[3]','nvarchar(1000)') AS VisitType
FROM 
    Activity
OUTER APPLY 
    XML.nodes('/ns:VisitActivityDetail/ns:VisitType') AS x(r)
WHERE
    ActivityTypeID = 2
```

Can you please help me understand what is wrong here?

Comment: Could you past the XML value?

Comment: Maybe BO expects the statement termination character `;` to be at the end instead of the beginning?

Comment: Try creating a new Query in IDT using objects from that Derived Table, then look at the generated SQL.  That should give you an indication of why it's not working.

Comment: I added the termination character ; at the end also, still no luck

Comment: Xml value:<VisitActivityDetail xmlns="Callaway.CRM.DAL.Objects.VisitActivityDetail" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><VisitDate>2018-02-23T12:00:00Z</VisitDate><VisitDateEnd>2018-02-23T13:00:00Z</VisitDateEnd><VisitType><ID>3</ID><OptionType>Visit</OptionType><Value>Sales Call</Value><SortOrder>3</SortOrder></VisitType></VisitActivityDetail>

Comment: Try creating a view (in the SQL Server database) with that definition, and change the derived table to be a simple SELECT from the view.

Comment: Try removing useless spaces